# Dynamically space apart children div to occupy full width of parent div

Tags: html, css, dynamic, fluid-layout

I have an html of the sort :

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child size3"></div>
  <div class="child size2"></div>
  <div class="child size2"></div>
  <div class="child size2"></div>
  <div class="child size1"></div>
</div>
```

The parent div is a single horizontal line of 100% width.
Now under different conditions maybe 3 children will be displayed, maybe 4 or maybe 5. I want the children to keep their sizes but according to the number of children being displayed, I want children to dynamically have space between them so as to occupy full width of the parent div.

**Note**: The structure is actually not this simple. Each child div may have a different size based on conditions so dynamic margin is what I am looking for. Each child div has a tree of it's own for purposes of angular usage so applying css to classes of children is not preferable. 
 What property can I apply to parent div so as to adjust the margin between children dynamically ? Please help.

**EDIT**
I have tried flex module but as I said each child has it's own dom tree and hence may not be the immediate child of parent div. In such cases the child is squished to a small size and the "size" property is lost.

Comment: I think the CSS flexbox module would probably work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Comment: is it supported by all browsers ?

Comment: Most features are well supported by the major browsers since about 2013, reference: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Pleas check edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```html
  .parent 
{
  display: -moz-flex; //for browser compatibilty
 display: -ms-flexbox; //for browser compatibilty
 display: -webkit-flex; //for browser compatibilty
 display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; //Use browser prefix for this
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-evenly; //use browswer prefix
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the jsfiddle for the code you are using as it is not clear what the size1 size2 you are mentioning.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible that whenever the inner div of a child div is set to `display:none` , it should set the outer child div also to `display:none` so that it does not occupy any space in the row.

Comment: Actually the solution is fine and my problem is now a different one.

Comment: To answer this I need the reference code, as it is not sure that which is your child dv and which is your parent div.

Comment: My problem has been solved. I was restricted from sharing detailed code sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJJzGZ

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

All you need is to use flex

https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties#justify-content

You have some minor bugs with IE11 but overall it's working fine

https://caniuse.com/#search=flex